# Beveling an extruded object

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, svg

I've got this logo as svg vector file, extruded it to make it 3d and assigned a simple material. Now the edges should get beveled, but it doesn't work. Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Bevel Tool won't work, because of too tight topology.
And without *Clamp Overlap* you'll get ugly artifacts.

You need to keep enough space for the beveled edges, use n-gons if necessary.

[image]